# Show HTML when flash fails?

Tags: html, flash

I am using jcupload whats nice is all i need to write is the below and the flash+js does the rest

```
<div id="jcupload_content"></div>
```

However this is the ONLY flash on my site. If the user doesnt have flash (think ipod) i'd like to fallback to an html implementation. How do i do it? I know logically ppl wont be uploading via ipods but if i were to play music i can use a flash audio player fallback to html5 audio in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Better to use HTML5 audio, then fallback to Flash, I'd say ;).

How are you embedding your Flash? If you're using `swfobject`, they give some great examples in their [documentation page](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation).

Comment: swfobject is definitely the way to go.

Comment: html5->flash is the idea but i am trying to avoid hackory with SM2 and hope they do it internally.

Comment: OK, cool, but I'm still not sure if I helped answer your question... are you using `swfobject`? Could you be? Do you still need help?

Comment: I wrote another question. and +1 on this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073209/javascript-function-for-flash-detection

Comment: @gmcalab notice that the object tags in the linked documentation (which is not from Adobe's site) has an inner object tag with a `data` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

[Swf Object](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) should help.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to place the flash, but in the div that you're placing the flash into, have alternate HTML content.

Like so:

```
<div id="flashDiv">
    <p>No flash!</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.embedSWF('myFlash.swf', 'flashDiv', width, height, 'flash.version.here', 'expressInstall.swf', flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
```

per swfobject [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation).