# javascript function for flash detection

Tags: html, flash

[I have another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073050/show-html-when-flash-fails) which i think is most easily solved by using javascript to find out if flash exist or not and dynamically modify the page. In my case place a placeholder, call jcupload code if flash exist or replace the placeholding div with my html

But the problem is i havent been able to find any javascript functions to tell me if flash is installed. All i found were html that displays alt html if flash isnt shown/enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.featureblend.com/javascript-flash-detection-library.html works for me every time.

Comment: I tried it out, it was easy :) http://jsfiddle.net/d56MZ/ -edit- the text `generate the **required** HTML` is pretty scary. Lucky i didnt have to do anything more then my link

Answer (score 0):

http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/download/detection_kit/

here you go check the client side map

Answer (score 0):

Chris's answer is probably the simplest given your situation, where your upload control handles the embedding, but for future readers it's worth checking out [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/), which can handle both the feature detection and the embedding. I believe something like this would work:

```
if (swfobject.getFlashPlayerVersion().major === 0)
{
    // Do alternate content stuff
}
else
{
    swfobject.embedSWF(flashUrl, "jcupload_content", width, height, "10.0.0", expressInstallUrl,
                       {}
                       { menu: "false", allowScriptAccess: "always", scale: "noScale", wmode: "transparent", salign: "lt" },
                       {});
}
```

Substitute in your own `flashUrl`, `width`, `height`, and `expressInstallUrl` values. You can use the second parameter to supply flashvars, the third to customize the params to the embedding, and the fourth to customize any attributes you want the resulting `object` or `embed` tags to have.

Comment: you seem to like swfobject a little too much ;). Using the js function i was able to solve this in <5mins. One line in my html app, another line added in jcupload and one jquery line in my js file to show the hidden alternative html. easy! It beats modifying min JS source or even 'other ppl code'

Comment: For sure :). As I said, this is for future users who come here after searching for "JavaScript flash detection" or something like that.